# Android 8 System App update effective only after reboot

Tags: android, android-source, package-managers, custom-rom

**TL;DR**: When updating system apps on android, the updated app is only started after reboot.

I am developing a custom ROM based on Android 8.1.2 for a custom device based on Rockchip RK3126c. I took the AOSP source from the board manufacturer and only modified the platform key and added two custom apps as system apps; one is privileged (shared `system` user), and one isn't, i.e. the first is located in `/system/priv-app` and signed with the platform key, and the second in `/system/app` and signed with its own key.

Both apps work, but when I try to update any of the two (via `adb shell pm install -r ...` or via Android Studio) the update doesn't take effect; the old version still runs, even after killing (`adb shell kill -9 ...` or throwing a null pointer exception) and restarting it. Only after a full reboot is the new version started. I did increment the `versionCode`. Before the reboot, `getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(...).versionCode` yields the *new* version number, while `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` gives the old one. This is both for `eng` and `user` builds.

While updating, `adb logcat` shows:

```
10-17 15:45:19.706  1048  1048 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
10-17 15:45:19.725  1058  1058 E asset   : setgid: Operation not permitted
10-17 15:45:22.563   336   362 I ActivityManager: Start proc 1062:com.android.defcontainer/u0a11 for service com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService
10-17 15:45:22.617  1062  1062 I zygote  : The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
10-17 15:45:22.739   336   362 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) PackageManager expire 1 line
10-17 15:45:22.820  1077  1077 I dex2oat : /system/bin/dex2oat --input-vdex-fd=-1 --output-vdex-fd=14 --compiler-filter=quicken --classpath-dir=/data/app/com.example.myapp-cdF84NESHVxl5UTZHVbRdg== --class-loader-context=PCL[]
10-17 15:45:22.832  1077  1077 W dex2oat : Could not reserve sentinel fault page
10-17 15:45:26.117  1077  1080 W dex2oat : Verification of boolean ao0.a(java.lang.String, long) took 130.568ms
10-17 15:45:28.960  1077  1077 I dex2oat : dex2oat took 6.142s (10.744s cpu) (threads: 4) arena alloc=17KB (17568B) java alloc=4MB (4274432B) native alloc=6MB (6543768B) free=1801KB (1844840B)
10-17 15:45:28.997   336   350 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.example.myapp appid=1000 user=-1: installPackageLI
10-17 15:45:29.009   336   362 W PackageManager: Trying to update system app code path from /system/priv-app/MyApp to /data/app/MyApp-cdF84NESHVxl5UTZHVbRdg==
10-17 15:45:29.010   336   362 W PackageManager: Code path for com.example.myapp changing from /system/priv-app/MyApp to /data/app/MyApp-cdF84NESHVxl5UTZHVbRdg==
10-17 15:45:29.010   336   362 W PackageManager: Resource path com.example.myapp changing from /system/priv-app/MyApp to /data/app/MyApp-cdF84NESHVxl5UTZHVbRdg==
10-17 15:45:29.205   242   242 E         : Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl1968223466.tmp: No such file or directory
10-17 15:45:29.205   242   242 E installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl1968223466.tmp: No such file or directory
10-17 15:45:29.213   336   362 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.example.myapp appid=1000 user=0: pkg removed
10-17 15:45:29.214  1048  1048 I Pm      : Package com.example.myapp installed in 9500 ms
10-17 15:45:29.239  1048  1048 I app_process: System.exit called, status: 0
10-17 15:45:29.239  1048  1048 I AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
```

After the reboot, further updates to the app *do* work - apparently, the problem only exists when changing the code path from `/system/[priv-]app` to `/data/app`, but not when the path is already `/data/app`.

The same thing worked fine on Android 7.1.2. Deep within the android framework there is probably some cache for the code paths of the apps which doesn't get updated after the app is overwritten. Anyone knows where that is located and how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling, I found it myself: The app was marked as `persistent` in the [manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#persistent), which causes the mentioned behaviour. It only worked on Android 7.1.2 because there was a vendor-specific modification that ignored the `persistent` flag.